# "Using the technique" vs "By using the technique"

Tags: grammar

I am confused about the following sentence:

> *We can check overlap using the technique in solution 1*

Why has the author written "*using*"?  Could we rephrase it as:

> *We can check overlap by using the technique in solution 1*

Can anyone explain the grammar of the original statement to me?